# Extend/Customize ValidateUser of MembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am implementing `MembershipProvider` class. Most of the methods are not implemented, and I am throwing `NotImplementedException` in those.

But ValidateUser is being used:

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string UserName, string Password)
```

Now what I want is to add some more parameters to it. Something like this will do the trick:

```
public override bool ValidateUser
    (
        string UserName,
        string Password,
        string IpAddress,
        string BrowserName
    )
```

This is an example. Once I could add some more parameters, I can combine them in an object and then make a call to database layer.

I have searched a lot but could not find a way which works. Some people say it cannot be done and some say it can be.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't inject those parameters like that. What you COULD do is use `HttpContext.Current` but its a pretty knarly implementation.

Comment: Thanks Aron. I put all the parameters as XML string and parse them later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Win. I required some more parameters too besides IP and browser info.

What I ended up doing it putting everything (`UserName`, `Password`, additional parameters) in XML and sending it as username. Then in `password`, I had a flag which looks if it should do something different.

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    if (password == "XML")
    {
        // This contains additional information in username.
        DatabaseLayerObject.ValidateUser(username);
    }
    else
    {
        // This is conventional call.
        DatabaseLayerObject.ValidateUser(username, password);
    }
}
```

*UPDATE 1:*

I am adding some more information to clarify my response.

When I want to send more information in addition to `username` and `password`, I will put all of them in XML, and store this information in `username`. E.g.:

```
<UserName>MyUserName</UserName>
<Password>MyPassword</Password>
<City>NameOfCity</City>
<Country>NameOfCountry</Country>
```

Now I need some indication in the `ValidateUser` method to know whether I am sending XML or not. This flag is in `password`, stored as any string of my choice.

Comment: Sorry but I am confused with how you plan to use this method. Internally? How do you ensure password is "XML"?

Comment: @SBirthare: I have updated my response. I hope this clears up the confusion. Please let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a custom membership provider means you want to override the membership provider's methods.

Although you are feel free to create your own methods inside the custom membership provider, you won't be able to call it.

If you want just **IpAddress** and **Browser**, you can use **HttpContext.Current.Request**` inside **ValidateUser** method.

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
   string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
   string browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Version;

   // Do something
}
```